# Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_polygon, x$x, x$y, index) : invalid color name in 'cluster' (package Mclust)

Tags: r, graph, cluster-analysis, mclust

I use the Model Based Clustering from the package mclust for a subset of my data set. MClust recommended 1 cluster. The following error was displayed in the graphical display:

```
WKA_ohneJB <- read.csv("WKA_ohneJB_PCA.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

WKA_ohneJB_scale <- scale (WKA_ohneJB)
set.seed(123)
WKA_ohneJB_scale_sub <- WKA_ohneJB_scale [c(1:8000) , c ("BASKETS_NZ", "LOGONS", "PIS", "PIS_AP",  "PIS_DV", "PIS_PL", "PIS_SHOPS",
                                         "EXIST_CUST", "WEB_CUST", "MOBILE_CUST", "TABLET_CUST", "LOGON_CUST_STEP2",
                                         "PIS_SDV", "PIS_SR", "QUANTITY", "WKA", "NEW_CUST")]
MC_Baur <- Mclust(WKA_ohneJB_scale_sub)

fviz_mclust(MC_Baur, "classification", geom = "point", pointsize = 1.0, palette = "jco")
```

> Error message: Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_polygon, x$x, x$y, index) : 
>     invalid color name in 'cluster'

Here is part of my data set:

```
dput(rbind(head(WKA_ohneJB, 10), tail(WKA_ohneJB, 10)))
structure(list(X = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
821039L, 821040L, 821041L, 821042L, 821043L, 821044L, 821045L, 
821046L, 821047L, 821048L), BASKETS_NZ = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
LOGONS = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), PIS = c(71L, 39L, 50L, 4L, 
13L, 4L, 30L, 65L, 13L, 31L, 111L, 33L, 3L, 46L, 11L, 8L, 
17L, 68L, 65L, 15L), PIS_AP = c(14L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 8L, 0L, 1L), 
PIS_DV = c(3L, 19L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 38L, 
8L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L), PIS_PL = c(0L, 5L, 8L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 6L, 32L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), PIS_SDV = c(18L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 0L), PIS_SHOPS = c(3L, 
24L, 13L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 28L, 2L, 11L, 71L, 16L, 2L, 5L, 
6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L), PIS_SR = c(19L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 23L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 32L, 1L, 
0L), QUANTITY = c(13L, 2L, 18L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 17L, 8L), WKA = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), NEW_CUST = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), EXIST_CUST = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), WEB_CUST = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), MOBILE_CUST = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), TABLET_CUST = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
LOGON_CUST_STEP2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 821039L, 821040L, 821041L, 
821042L, 821043L, 821044L, 821045L, 821046L, 821047L, 821048L
), class = "data.frame")
```